# How to implement a background execution in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I would like to download part of data from the server when I click one button, and downloading other parts in background. How to implement this?

Comment: Javascript does not have threads

Comment: @aaronman , then how to implement that?

Comment: Javascript, in browsers, *do* have threads, now; they're called Web Workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: You can serialise several callback events using setTimeout() or use Web Workers if you can.

Comment: What you are looking for is called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Comment: @aaronman he didn't mention threads. They're but one mechamism of concurrency.

Comment: You could use the excellent Lazy Load plugin : http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html, http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 2):

If you are targetting HTML5 compatible browsers take a look at **Web Workers** :

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Background processes with web workers:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIdkYaLbzMs

Answer (score 0):

You have only one execution thread, so you will have to play with setInterval() and clearInterval() and execute your code based on timers :

```
var iv= setInterval(function(){ alert("Running now!"); }, 3000);
```

Clear the periodic function with :

```
clearInterval(iv);
```

Comment: What if the interval is not decided?

Comment: You probably have a start condition, so you can check it in the provided function before anything else.